# Someone can solve this problem?

Tags: customer, customer-account

```
2018-07-17T20:04:13+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: Invalid method Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::cleanPasswordsValidationData(Array
```

(
)
)
Trace: #0 /home/cdqkqjkb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(821): Varien_Object->__call('cleanPasswordsV...', Array)

## 1 /home/cdqkqjkb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(821): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData()

## 2 /home/cdqkqjkb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->resetPasswordPostAction()

## 3 /home/cdqkqjkb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('resetpasswordpo...')

## 4 /home/cdqkqjkb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

## 5 /home/cdqkqjkb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

## 6 /home/cdqkqjkb/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

## 7 /home/cdqkqjkb/public_html/index.php(102): Mage::run('', 'store')

## 8 {main}

Answer (score 0):

try replacing AccountController.php
http://freegento.com/doc/df/d10/_customer_2controllers_2_account_controller_8php-source.html

Comment: Many thanks Sanya for your answer, but I have tryed and i take blank page on register and login ,.worse then before,.problably some change in other folder,..i don't know,.